# What is the best way to to put 2 big div on the left and 4 smaller div on the right?

Tags: html, css

I want to put 2 big divs on the left, and 4 smaller divs on the right, what's the best way to do it without adding container to 2 big divs? Adding that container will be my last resort.

I've tried using `float:left` for 2 big divs, and `float:right` for smaller divs, but of course it's failed.

Here's what I want (w better pic):
[image]

Here's what I tried with failed CSS

```css
.big {
width: 40%;
float:left;
height: 200px;
background: blue;
margin: 5px;
}



.small {
width: 40%;
float:right;
height: 50px;
background: red;
margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="big">BIG</div>
    <div class="big">BIG</div>
    <div class="small">SMALL</div>
    <div class="small">SMALL</div>
    <div class="small">SMALL</div>
    <div class="small">SMALL</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you want looks terribly unordered from the designer's eye, are you sure you want that?

Comment: That's raw design, after some styling it will look good. Here's my inspiration for it http://prntscr.com/o7zhbp Do you think this is bad? I think it's unusual but it's good. I want to double the item in it.

Comment: You can try to use some framework like bootstrap and get it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About float, you need to know how to deal with it

You could do (+ css to look alike your sketch) :

```css
[class] {
  border:1em rgb(220, 207, 5) solid;
  background:rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color:white;
  padding:0.5em;
  margin:2px;
  overflow:hidden;/* because of float */
  height:10vh
}
.big {
  float:left;
  clear:left;/* stack those two */
  height:35vh;
  width:30%;
  margin-top:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="big">BIG</div>
    <div class="big">BIG</div>
    <div class="small">SMALL</div>
    <div class="small">SMALL</div>
    <div class="small">SMALL</div>
    <div class="small">SMALL</div>
</div>
```

You can read about : https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Nowdays, the best would be `display:grid` (see the other answer)

---

Else, **If the left area is about a picture and a text underneath**, a single container can be used there and you can use `display:table`/`table-cell` to mind the old browsers too.

```css
body [id] {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing:2px;
}

body [class] {
  border: 1em rgb(220, 207, 5) solid;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 2px 2px 0;
}
.big img {
max-width:45vw;/* for the samll snippet demo here */
}
body .big {
  display: table-cell;/* only that one ! */
  width: 0;          /* biggest element will give the width */
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <figure class="big">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/500x300">
    <figcaption>
      <h1>title</h1>
      <p>text or else</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <div class="small">SMALL</div>
  <div class="small">SMALL</div>
  <div class="small">SMALL</div>
  <div class="small">SMALL</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is an interesting answer! Grid and table won't work, too rigid, `.big` and `.small` contain text, so its height is undetermined. I have question about your first answer, why `.small` able to occupy the whole screen to the right while there's no mention about its `width`?

Comment: @somuch72  its about formating context and dealing with float . (see the link i gave in ) . About display:table , it works in every browser including IE8.(not grid nor flex)

Comment: Good reading! I was confused with `clear` that's why I can't make it work before I ask here! I know overflow can be used to give dimension to float, but I usually only use it to its parent. And this made me remember that by default, div takes the whole screen width. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> CSS Flex

```css
.large, .small {
   border: 5px solid yellow;
   padding: 10;
   width: 100px;
   background-color: black;
   color: white;
}

#right-container {
   margin-left: 2px;
}

.large {
   height: 100px;
}

.small {
   height: 30px;
   margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex">
   <div id="left-container">
      <div id="left-top" class="large">LARGE</div>
      <div id="left-bottom" class="large">LARGE</div>
   </div>
   <div id="right-container">
      <div id="right-1" class="small">SMALL</div>
      <div id="right-2" class="small">SMALL</div>
      <div id="right-3" class="small">SMALL</div>
      <div id="right-4" class="small">SMALL</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems there's no other way without additional container(s)

Comment: None that I can think of... Unless you go the route of setting `absolute` or `fixed` positions on everything and then positioning your items with Javascript or something like that. But a couple of sensible wrapper/container divs is a totally valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS-Grid**

*Note this will cause the odd numbered small element to align with the top of large ones in rows. If this is not the desired behaviour then wrapping elements will be required.*

```css
#parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.big {
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.small {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="big">BIG</div>
  <div class="big">BIG</div>
  <div class="small">SMALL</div>
  <div class="small">SMALL</div>
  <div class="small">SMALL</div>
  <div class="small">SMALL</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is good, but not fully fluid. Maybe I put bad picture for this. The `.small` div should be glued to each other with only margin to separate them. I'll put better pic.

Comment: Yeah...you'll need wrappers to do that.